# Correct syntax for adding a command

Tags: ace-editor

Did the syntax for command objects change? I have been using the following:

```
editor.addCommand({
    name: "find",
    bindKey: {win: "Ctrl-F", mac: "Cmd-F"},
    exec: findKeyboardHandler});
```

- Should I write out, "Command-F" instead of "cmd-f"?
- Is it case sensitive?
- What if I add a key binding that are already defined?
- Is the command name unique?
- Are listeners added on the capture phase or bubble phase?
- Does the command name matter? Are there any reserved names, "save", "render"?
- Does the argument count ever change? Is it always one parameter passed back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ace command syntax had not changed for a long time

- All of `Command`, `cmd`, `Cmd` work the same see [ace/lib/keys.js#L51-L52](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/lib/keys.js#L51-L52)
- keybindings are not case sensitive
- if keybinding is already defined, the new one will be added to command stack, and the last added one will be called first, if it is not available the next one will be added.
- command name is unique, if a command with same name exists, old one will be removed.
- listener is added to the bubble phase [ace/lib/event.js#L348](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/lib/event.js#L348)
- there are no reserved names, but using command named `__proto__`, will break [keyboard/hash_handler.js#L40](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/keyboard/hash_handler.js#L40)
- command always gets two arguments, `editor` and `args` object [ace/commands/command_manager.js#L24](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/commands/command_manager.js#L24)

Comment: args is usually an empty object, but using editor.execCommand you can pass something else to the command

Comment: How do you prevent the default event handler from firing? For example, if you set Cmd-O to do something new, how do you prevent the browser from opening the Open File dialogue?

Comment: if the command doesn't return false and doesn't throw, ace calls e.preventDefault preventing the default action on browsers that allow preventing it. On which browser and for which key do you see a problem?

Answer (score 0):

To call addCommand, you have to call commands:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'quit',
    exec: function(){
        yourQuitFunctionHere();
    }
});
```

then you can use the command for keybindings or exec directly:

```
editor.execCommand('quit');
```